# typescript generic function returning same type as parameter

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Trying to write a function that can take a single value or array as the parameter, handle it appropriately and return the same type.

Tried this:

```
myFunc = <T extends string | string[]>(parm1: T): T =>
{
  if (Array.isArray(parm1)) {
    return parm1.map(p => p);
  } else {
    // Simplest thing is just to recurse with the value in an array.
    return this.myFunc([parm1])[0];
    };
}
```

Logically, it should work, right? If `parm1` is an array, I always return a string array. If it's a string, I always return a string. But I get this:

> Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'T'.
> 'string[]' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'string | string[]'.ts(2322)

I can force it like so:

```
myFunc = <T extends string | string[]>(parm1: T): T =>
{
  if (Array.isArray(parm1)) {
    return parm1.map(p => p) as T;
  } else {
    // Simplest thing is just to recurse with the value in an array.
    return this.myFunc([parm1])[0] as T;
    };
}
```

But brute-forcing like this feels like cheating. How can I do this without the heavy-handed assertion? Is there really something for typescript to be complaining about here? Or is this a corner case that typescript just doesn't understand?

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a constrained version of an identity function:

```ts
function identity <T>(value: T): T {
  return value;
}
```

You can use an [overloaded function signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) to match the type of input:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDAJgUzLKBPRAeAFQD4AKANwEMAbENALkQIEoGDEBvAKEUQCc0oIXkko00Abk4BfTp1CRYCRBAQBnKLwowwaFAEl0mGDnxs0ADygYUqxOt7aA5qVG1WLRpPnR4SFWHstHX1DLFxCRAsrMBs7DScAbQBdF2o3Rg8CL3AfJX9A7V0DDDDTSMtrW3snRAAfOIcwR2TUsXcObj4BIRE0iWlZfKhEVzQARkQAXmU1DSCi0ONsEgSAcmA4OFWAGkRVgCMKXlWkpkkeHgB6S4A9AH5OIZG+gCYpmYC5wpCSpZJ1zarM6dK63B5AA)

```ts
function constrainedIdentity <T extends string>(value: T): T;
function constrainedIdentity <T extends string[]>(value: T): T;
function constrainedIdentity <T extends string | string[]>(value: T) {
  return value;
}

const value1 = constrainedIdentity(['foo', 'bar']);
    //^? const value1: string[]
const value2 = constrainedIdentity('foo');
    //^? const value2: "foo"
```

This pattern gives you the flexibility to adjust the return type for each call signature, in the case that you decide to transform the resulting value in some way, for example:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFATgQzAZ2HFBbRAHgBVEBTADyjLABNNFNUYwBzAPgAoA3NAGxBkAXImIBKEWBB4ARmRQBuAFChIsBMnRYc+IqUrU6DJihasA2gF0uvAcNETEU2fKvLV0eElQZsuAiTkVDT0jMxsiAA+YaZsVjb8giLiiADeSoiIKGRQIChIAIIo6ACeAHQwmEWlPIlkYhmZiAD8iLaCZXhoAA6cAHLScigNTYgiAy4otXZiygC+SkoQCExtdQCMiAC8mr46eJzmAOQ4cEcANIhHMmgoR5azjZkA9M8Aes1LK1BrdgBM2122n8nBOcDOj1Grw+SiAA)

```ts
function transform <T extends string>(value: T): number;
function transform <T extends string[]>(value: T): number[];
function transform <T extends string | string[]>(value: T) {
  return Array.isArray(value)
    ? value.map(Number)
    : Number(value);
}

const value1 = transform(['foo', 'bar']);
    //^? const value1: number[]
const value2 = transform('foo');
    //^? const value2: number
```

---

On (the problems with) the code shown in the question:

*Ignoring the `string` possibility for a moment...*

In the case of an array input, if your actual goal is to `map` it (and that wasn't just a contrived bit of implementation code in your example), here's *one* reason why the implementation that you showed doesn't match the return type:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwJ4DFwUQHgCqICmAHlIWACYDOiVUATjGAOYDaAugHwAUADgIb1kARgBciPAEpxBAN4AoRInqEoIekgFDhAOmT9efRAF5OiXpIDciAPQAqRYgB+L12-ce3jvKl6FEAOR0jCwcAYgwNGBwUIj8VFQwzGD8AEYANv5QcIhQvv4BeAE6jkEMTGzs4ZFxCUkpGVk5UAAW-hAIwfxMsXDAufmBRQA0iKkgUKVFiB0g6RRj-kx0-GCw-GQLAO4wrXGIFDDAwIQqa7QgqXl+iH0znQzd52UhlcXcAEwAzB8fkoh2GzyAC+8nkNhsiAAEqdCEE4khBPR+KhEDs9vxaH4IDB+OkiKRkeZ6HA-PQ8qJ5B0wHQ4qlsMZEAB5VIAK0I0B08USyW4rAC-ACowCqSFgQgAXYo1kWI5uPSAAUSbxxEFsfLEAA3PEgOGIYFWRy2GwAPQA-GDqVQ4JkdOk4MxuGkIDoqOq8UrSVZjYgAERuuV4rU6wi+sEQiRtW6MZhMIPXJY0Xgk4gwQgLVKo1r+UCQWAISlW2LAMAAJUIVDmsUZaEwkCd9MNSmN5vDkKhcC2hE1p1GrQ28OisX40BAePSWfousLnRthDtDu4JfLlfSUFd7sVyu9EfAFEIwCY6bbkf8Knjg0iM5psX0vBXVZMdJdd+4wRMZmCTaUENbQA)

```ts
function myFunc <T extends string[]>(parm1: T): T {
  return parm1.map(p => p); /*
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'T'.
  'string[]' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but
  'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'string[]'.(2322) */
}

// Here's an array with a special extra property:
const abc = Object.assign(['a', 'b', 'c'], { specialProp: 'special value' });
   //^? const abc: string[] & { specialProp: string }

console.log(abc.specialProp); // "special value"

// The original type is proxied by the function:
const fnResult = myFunc(abc);
   //^? const fnResult: string[] & { specialProp: string }

// However, that's not actually true:
console.log(fnResult.specialProp); // undefined

// The real type is:
const mapResult = abc.map(str => str);
   //^? const mapResult: string[]
```

Comment: But now you can return anything in `transform`!

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73993012/typescript-generic-function-returning-same-type-as-parameter/73993082#comment130647661_73993082) @caTS Not anything (https://tsplay.dev/WPpxJW): If the implementation is egregiously mismatched, you'll still get a compiler error: `This overload signature is not compatible with its implementation signature.(2394)` But it does allow for some flexibility, which is by design.

Comment: Well here's the peculiar thing... [TypeScript doesn't care in an if statement, but it does with a ternary](https://tsplay.dev/wRX9Qm). I did not expect this behavior so my comment is not correct here.

Comment: Nope, I am just being dumb again... I marked the return types of the two functions differently. Sorry for the confusion. Wait, if I correct it, I still get different behaviors... https://tsplay.dev/mq3Qrw

Answer (score 1):

Why about moving the generic type into the union type instead, i.e. `T` being able to be either `T` or `T[]` instead? The first step is to do something like this:

```
const myFunc: IOverload = <T extends string>(parm1: T | T[]): T | T[] =>
{
  if (Array.isArray(parm1)) {
    return parm1.map(p => p);
  } else {
    // Simplest thing is just to recurse with the value in an array.
    return myFunc([parm1])[0];
    };
}

myFunc(['1','2','3']);
myFunc('1');
```

But notice that the typing of both `myFunc(['1','2','3'])` and `myFunc(1)` will return the same union type. We can easily solve this with overloads:

```
type MyFuncOverload = {
    <T extends string>(parm1: T): T,
    <T extends string>(parm1: T[]): T[],
}

const myFunc: MyFuncOverload = (parm1) =>
{
  if (Array.isArray(parm1)) {
    return parm1.map(p => p);
  } else {
    // Simplest thing is just to recurse with the value in an array.
    return myFunc([parm1])[0];
    };
}

myFunc(['1','2','3']);  // Inferred type is `string[]`
myFunc('1');            // Inferred type is `string`
```

See example on [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiBiBXAdgYwPIDcICcA2A9gIYAmUAvFAN4BQU9UAPACpQQAewEyJAzlL2A4AlsgDmAPgAUYIjgC2ARgBcUZgEpVzADR0GLNp258BQ0ZJlylWgNoBdTWvu6AvjRqoCyQVHkIUqKpwSGhYuISkFFCWCorqFBI0tPTCAGbRAII4OEQgAHTCvFk5IDFK6vHJDDgQwIg4yFCysXnyRGAyCU3qANx6Lmx4vNBV9AD0Y1AAysLyYHgQPsAAFuZQhVAAVohLBFA1qPXDUADuwitQK9CYRHiI0KJQRI1yJXl69DV1Db7+aFI2ZpKBw2AAMdj6DCgLj6bhofhCqABAHJFMjtMiAEzo5EAZmRDh640mAElkKlcDUyKBIOt+AADQQicT2enwv5I1HI3pQ3kMCZQMkU7IQangB4MpnmelAA).

Comment: A downside is that you can return anything in one of the branches and it won't complain.

Comment: @caTS Can you show an example?

Comment: Sure, [here](https://tsplay.dev/wRX9Qm) I am returning `0` in one of the branches. If I return something else in the other branch, *then* I get an error. Odd isn't it...

Comment: @caTS typescript reported an error in your code up line 2. "This overload signature is not compatible with its implementation signature."

Comment: @JCFord Oh I guess TypeScript just decided to skip work today for me.

Answer (score -1):

Your code isn't type correct, because a caller could write the following:

```
class A extends Array<string> {
  foo() {
    console.log("Hello from foo");
  }
}

const a = myFunc(new A());
a.foo();
```

This compiles just fine, because myFunc promises to return an instance of the same type it is passed, which has a member foo, but fails at runtime, because myfunc lied and returned an object of a different prototype, which doesn't have a foo.

That is, the key point you're missing is that type parameters are specified by the caller, and `K extends string | string[]` really means that `K` *extends* `string` or `string[]`, so `K` can be `string`, `string[]`, or any subtype thereof. But if it is a subtype, your implementation of myFunc doesn't return an instance of that type. And that's why the compiler says:

> Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'T'.
> 'string[]' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different **subtype** of constraint 'string | string[]'.(2322)

(emphasis mine)

It's not complaining that `string[]` might not be `string[]`, but that `T` might have been instantiated with a *subtype* of `string[]`, and `string[]` may not be assignable to that *subtype*.

The correct typing for your function is an overload type:

```
  myFunc(s: string) : string;
  myFunc(a: string[]): string[];
  myFunc(parm1: string | string[]) {
    if (Array.isArray(parm1)) {
        return parm1.map(p => p);
    } else {
        // Simplest thing is just to recurse with the value in an array.
        return this.myFunc([parm1])[0];
    };
  }
```

Now, the parameter is either `string` or `string[]`, and we promise to return a `string` or a `string[]`, respectively. We make no special guarantees with respect to subtypes of `string` or `string[]`, so if a subtype of `string[]` is passed, `myFunc` will treat this like any `string[]`, and return a simple `string[]`, not an instance of that special array type.

Comment: @caTS: It answers the question "Is there really something for typescript to be complaining about here?" with "yes there is: if typescript were to accept your code, the following code would compile, but fail at runtime with a type error".

Comment: Your answer explains why the type assertion solution is less than ideal, but doesn't explain why typescript doesn't like the code without the assertions.

Comment: My answer explains that your code is not type correct, because it promises to return the same type the caller used, but fails to do so if the caller were to pass a subtype of `string[]`. That's why TypeScript doesn't like your code. You can use type assertions to lie to the compiler, and get it to back off. But the issue it raises is valid (if rare in practice, because most people would not extend a string or string[]) and the proper fix is to refrain from using `extends` when you don't mean it, and use an overload instead.